# In Illustrator, how do I paste in place one object on multiple artboard in the same place?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a problem when I use "paste in all artboards" it's always moving objects slightly
[image]
Thank you for your anserws!

Comment: One has to consider... is the paste in place moving objects or are the manually placed guides just slightly different.